# How to get Previous textbox value when click on <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Below is my code and i am trying to get value of the above text box when click on the `<a>` which is in same div. I mean to say if i click on second "add to cart" link than it will give me "test2" as per my screenshot.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){

    alert($('.ProductActionAdd a').prevAll(".ProductActionAdd a:first").attr('value'));
})
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ProductActionAdd">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <a class="button" href="#">Add To Cart</a>
</div>
<div class="ProductActionAdd">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <a class="button" href="#">Add To Cart</a>
</div>
<div class="ProductActionAdd">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <a class="button" href="#">Add To Cart</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but not getting success.
[image: this is my project image]

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the input is the previous sibling element of the clicked anchor element so use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) (`$(this).prev()`)

Also to get the value of the element use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function () {
        alert($(this).prev().val());
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jaeuD/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the `textbox`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){ 
        alert($(this).prev().val());   
        alert($('.ProductActionAdd a').prevAll(".ProductActionAdd a:first").attr('id'));
    });
});
```

**Description:** Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .prev() method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements
>   in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that can be passed to the $() function. If the selector is supplied,
>   the preceding element will be filtered by testing whether it match the
>   selector, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){    
    alert($(this).closest(':input').val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().val());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this task using jquery `$(this)`. There are more than one way exist to achieve this task.

You can try jquery [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)  :

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev().val());        
});
```

Or you can also try to find input into parent container, using jquery [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){    
    alert($(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').val());    
});
```

[Try also in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCE82/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){
alert($(this).closest('div').find('input').attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BmkL8/

Answer (score 0):

**Check this:**

```
$(".ProductActionAdd a").click(function(){

    $(this).prev("input[type=text]").val();
});
```